# Pywinauto _ List Box unable to select multiple items

Tags: python, listbox, pywinauto

I am trying to select multiple items from a ListBox, but unable to get it done. Below is my code snippet.
Also " can_select_multiple" returns "0".. what does it mean?

```
app =Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re='CAESAR II Output Report Options').Dialog
print(app.ListBox.can_select_multiple())
for x in [1,2,3]:
    app.ListBox.select(x)
```

[control identifiers attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR8xW.png)
[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldOm0.png)